# Let X be a uniform r.v. over (−1, 1). Let Y = X^2.

Tags: covariance

I'm having problems solving this problem
"Let X be a uniform r.v. over (−1, 1). Let $Y = X^n.$
Calculate:
the covariance of X and Y.

I believe that i should use:
$$ cov(x,y) = E(x,y) - E(x)E(y)$$
but i don't understand  how am i supposed to calculate $E\{x\}$ or $E\{y \}$.

if my logic is correct the statement " Let X be a uniform r.v. over (−1, 1)" could translate to $E\{x\} = \frac{1}{2}$ but then i can't see how to calculate $E\{y \}$. Can someone put me on the right track please?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{E}(X^a)=\int_{-1}^1{1\over 2}x^a\mathrm{d}x$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MatthewPilling thanks for the clue, it helped me a lot. :D

Comment: Titles should summarize, rather than state the beginning of an exercise.